# Unable to Azure Login within GitHub Action after moving from Repo Variables to Environment Variables

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

I have the following environments setup within GitHub Actions:

development, testing and production

I have the following secret, this secret is basically a service principal within Azure, before it use to be a variable but as we've added more environments we're using secrets as we have different service principal for each env.

It was created with the command shown in the example link below.

Secret name: AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPLE

I have the following workflow:

```
name: Build and Deploy To Development Environment
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development
    
jobs:
  build:
    environment: development
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}
```

No matter what I do, it always fails to login with the error

Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner.

So two things,

setting `environment: development` will allow me access secrets within the Environment development secrets? and secondly, why since moving from repo variables to environment secrets does this no longer allow me sign in? I have followed the exact steps within this [link](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md) and made sure that the service principal is correctly created within Azure AD

Comment: Does `secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL` contain whole json like client_id, client_secret etc?

Answer (score 0):

- In the question you mentioned secret name is **AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPLE**, but in the workflow you have given **AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL**.

[image]

- Make sure you are using the correct SECRET name in the GitHub workflow.
- Make sure you are giving the correct value/exact Json output of the command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myApp" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group} --sdk-auth`  as the SECRET value in GitHub.

```
{
  "clientId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "clientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "subscriptionId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "tenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "activeDirectoryEndpointUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "resourceManagerEndpointUrl": "https://management.azure.com/",
  "activeDirectoryGraphResourceId": "https://graph.windows.net/",
  "sqlManagementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/",
  "galleryEndpointUrl": "https://gallery.azure.com/",
  "managementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net/"
}
```

---

I followed the same document to configure the GitHub actions for web app using SECRETs as environment variables.
I could configure and deploy the web app without any issues.

- Created a new Secret in my GitHub repository and added Json output as its value.

[image]

- Using the Secret name in my GitHub workflow to login to Azure and start the deployment.

**My Workflow:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - pravuwebapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'pravuwebapp'
          slot-name: 'Development'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL}}
```

**Deployment Status:**

[image]

[image]